# Override size of a parameter that is an array of a struct in systemverilog

Tags: arrays, verilog, system-verilog, hdl, register-transfer-level

i have a module parameter that is an array of a predefined struct.  I set the default size of this array as 1 element.  The idea is to override it with the appropriate size at the time of instantiation.

The way i show below doesn't override the size.  It only overides the first value.  I can see why it would do this as the size field is not parameterized.  Is there a better way than to pass a parameter for the size?

Thank you for the help.

```
    module reg_slave
      #(parameter
         reg_pkg::defval_pair [0:0] REG_DEFVAL  = '0 //param decl with size=1
       )();
     endmodule : reg_slave

    module top();
      localparam reg_pkg::defval_pair [1:0] REG_DEFVAL = '{ 
         {3,'h32},
         {0,'h1}
         };  //param of same type and size = 2

      reg_slave #(
                   .REG_DEFVAL(REG_DEFVAL) //trying to override the size.
                 )  
      reg_slave_inst ();

    endmodule : top

    package reg_pkg;
      typedef struct packed { int ADDR; bit [31:0] VAL;} defval_pair;
    endpackage : reg_pkg
```

Comment: Reading a bit more and trying to understand the type parameter, I wonder if we can use the type parameter itself... i.e. we typedef one type that has one array element which gets overridden by another type parameter that has the necessary number of array elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using type parameter. However, you still need an extra parameter to pass into the instance. The advantage is that you can change a parameter's type.

```
module reg_slave
  #(parameter
     type T = int,
     T REG_DEFVAL  = '0 //param decl with size=1
   )();
 endmodule : reg_slave

module top();
  localparam reg_pkg::defval_pair [1:0] REG_DEFVAL = '{ 
     {3,'h32},
     {0,'h1}
     };  //param of same type and size = 2

  reg_slave #(
               .T(reg_pkg::defval_pair[1:0]),
               .REG_DEFVAL(REG_DEFVAL) //trying to override the size.
             )  
  reg_slave_inst ();

endmodule : top
```

Comment: Thanks @jclin for pointing out the type parameter.  It led me to think about my comment to the question above.

Comment: Sorry I didn't quite follow the first time what you were suggesting here.  But I accepted this answer now after I went through it again.

Answer (score 2):

You need an additional parameter for the size:

```
module reg_slave
      #(parameter
      int SIZE=1,
     reg_pkg::defval_pair [SIZE-1:0] REG_DEFVAL  = '0 //param decl with size=1
   )();
endmodule : reg_slave
```

You have a few errors in assigning `REG_DEFVAL` in `top`. `REG_DEFVAL` is a packed array, therefore remove the single quite. `defval_pair` is a `packed struct`, therefore the  entries need a cast assignment:

```
module top();
  localparam int SIZE=2;
  localparam reg_pkg::defval_pair [SIZE-1:0] REG_DEFVAL = { // no single quite
     reg_pkg::defval_pair'{3,'h32}, // cast as defval_pair
     reg_pkg::defval_pair'{0,'h1} // cast as defval_pair
     };  //param of same type and size = 2

  reg_slave #( .SIZE(SIZE), // override size
               .REG_DEFVAL(REG_DEFVAL)
             )  
  reg_slave_inst ();

endmodule : top
```

---

***UPDATE***: Passing a N size array parameter without passing a SIZE parameter.

**Note**: this is most likely *not* synthesisable. SystemVeilog support for this feature may vary between simulators.

```
module reg_slave
      #(parameter
     reg_pkg::defval_pair REG_DEFVAL [] = '{ reg_pkg::defval_pair'{0,'h0} } //param decl with size=1
   )();
endmodule : reg_slave

module top();
  localparam reg_pkg::defval_pair REG_DEFVAL [] = '{ // with single quite
     reg_pkg::defval_pair'{3,'h32}, // cast as defval_pair
     reg_pkg::defval_pair'{0,'h1} // cast as defval_pair
     };  //param of same type and size = 2

  reg_slave #(
               .REG_DEFVAL(REG_DEFVAL)
             )  
  reg_slave_inst ();

endmodule : top
```

Comment: Thanks Greg.  Especially so for pointing out the cast operator.  Sounds like I really cannot get away without a size  parameter.

Comment: @shparekh There is a way to not pass a size parameter. See the updated to my answer. Just be away that some tools may not have full implemented this SystemVerilog feature.