# variable-sized parameter array in verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim

I am observing odd behaviour when simulating a design with a parameter array in (system)verilog.

Here is my module interface:

```
module src_multi
#(
    parameter NUM_DEST = 4,                  
    parameter [N_ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] DEST [0:NUM_DEST-1] //problematic line
)
(
    ...
);
```

and the instantiation of that module in the testbench:

```
src_multi
#(
    .NUM_DEST(3),
    .DEST('{13,12,8})
)
src_src1_outbun
(
      ...
);
```

The idea is basically I want `DEST` to be an array of numbers, and the number of entries should depend on `NUM_DEST`. However, when `DEST` is declared as shown above but not initialized:

```
parameter [N_ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] DEST [0:NUM_DEST-1]
```

modelsim always reads the value `0` from DEST, as if it was full of zeroes.

if I initialize the array as follows:

```
parameter [N_ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] DEST [0:NUM_DEST-1] = '{0,1,2,3}
```

I get a runtime simulation error:

```
# ** Fatal: (vsim-120) Illegal Concat. Number of elements doesn't match with the type.
```

this is because in my instantiation, I want the array to be of size 3. So I tried initializing it with size 3 (as follows), and that works perfectly!

```
parameter NUM_DEST = 3,
parameter [N_ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] DEST [0:NUM_DEST-1] = '{0,1,2}
```

but this forces me to only use one size for that array, but I want it to have a variable size.

How can I use a variable-sized parameter array in (system)verilog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out this is a modelsim bug. This input yields different results on two different modelsim versions:

```
parameter NUM_DEST = 4,
parameter [N_ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] DEST [0:NUM_DEST-1]
```

modelsim 10.3d = correct

[image: modelsim 10.3d = correct]

modelsim 10.1e = wrong

[image: modelsim 10.1e = wrong]

To fix it in all cases, we can initialize the array with the parametrized number of inputs `NUM_DEST` as follows:

```
parameter NUM_DEST = 4,
parameter [N_ADDR_WIDTH-1:0] DEST [0:NUM_DEST-1] = '{NUM_DEST{1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought the last one would work, what kind of error do you get when you try to override it with a different sized array?

You might try using a parameterized type like in this question: [Override size of a parameter that is an array of a struct in systemverilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18627235/override-size-of-a-parameter-that-is-an-array-of-a-struct-in-systemverilog)

Comment: I get this error (also written in the question) `# ** Fatal: (vsim-120) Illegal Concat. Number of elements doesn't match with the type.`

Comment: oops, sorry I missed that. I presume you also changed NUM_DEST at the same time?